# xUnit, Moq Setup for Multiple Parameters return null instead of Object

Tags: c#, xunit, .net-5, autofixture

I am working on xUnit test using moq and Fixture in .NET CORE 5 application.

My implementation class called `QueryResultSummaryHelper` to get `QueryResultSummary` object by calling `GetReport` Method. I have multiple `GetReport` methods with different parameter sets.

In Test class I am using `Setup` on QueryResultSummaryHelper moq object and it return correct object with value where there are 3 parameters however in another class I am trying to `Setup` on `GetReport` with 4 parameter and getting `NULL` value, not sure what I am missing from the puzzle??

`QueryResultHelper Defination`

```
 public interface IQueryResultHelper
{
    QueryResultSummary GetReport(int recordsCount, bool error, dynamic dataObject);
    QueryResultSummary GetReport(int recordsCount, bool error, Exception e);
    QueryResultSummary GetReport(int recordsCount, bool error, string customMessage, dynamic dataObject);
    QueryResultSummary GetReport(int recordsCount, bool error, string customMessage, Exception e);
}
```

I am trying to setup following method...

```
 QueryResultSummary GetReport(int recordsCount, bool error, string customMessage, dynamic dataObject);
```

`Test Class`

```
public class SiteEntityTest : SetUps
{
    private readonly SiteEntity sut;

    public SiteEntityTest() 
    {
        sut = new SiteEntity(
            appAmbientStateMoq.Object, 
            queryResultHelperMoq.Object,
           );
    }

    [Fact]
    [Trait("Method", "GetSite")]
    public async Task ShouldReturn_Site_IfExist()
    {
       // other arrange code...
        var queryResultSummaryMoq = new QueryResultSummary
        {
            RecordsCount = siteMoq == null ? 0 : 1,
            IsRecordExist = true,
            Error = false,
            ExecutionMessage = QueryExecutionStatusEnum.Success.ToString(),
            Exceptions = (Exception)null,
            CustomMessage = SiteSearchStatus
        };


        queryResultHelperMoq.Setup(x => x.GetReport(
           siteWithStatusDataViewMoq == null ? 0 : 1,
           false,
           SiteSearchStatus,
           siteWithStatusDataViewMoq
           )).Returns(queryResultSummaryMoq);

    }
```

the following Setup in another class does work and return object value and not Null

```
 queryResultHelperMoq.Setup(x => x.GetReport(
           contraventionGuideImageMoq == null ? 0 : 1,
           false,
           contraventionGuideImageMoq
           )).Returns(queryResultSummaryMoq);
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `It.IsAny<dynamic>()` instead of  `siteWithStatusDataViewMoq` as the last parameter in the `Setup`?

Comment: I am trying like It.IsAny<dynamic>(siteWithStatusDataViewMoq) but I think is incorrect syntax

Comment: You don't have to pass the `siteWithStatusDataViewMoq` to the `It.IsAny`. Call it without passing any parameter, just like I did in the previous comment

Comment: it throw error  queryResultHelperMoq.Setup(x => x.GetReport(
               siteWithStatusDataViewMoq == null ? 0 : 1,
               false,
               SiteSearchStatus,
               It.IsAny<dynamic>()
               )).Returns(queryResultSummaryMoq);

Comment: I have tried  following and it worked  queryResultHelperMoq.Setup(x => x.GetReport(
               siteWithStatusDataViewMoq == null ? 0 : 1,
               false,
               SiteSearchStatus,
               It.IsAny<SiteWithStatusDataView>()
               )).Returns(queryResultSummaryMoq);

Comment: many thanks... but still don't understand by passing It.IsAny<SiteWithStatusDataView>() how it knows what data I am passing! because I am just passing object reference

Comment: `It.IsAny` means: do not care about the instance itself, check only the type.

Answer (score 0):

```
queryResultHelperMoq.Setup(x => x.GetReport(
   siteWithStatusDataViewMoq == null ? 0 : 1,
   false,
   SiteSearchStatus,
   It.IsAny<SiteWithStatusDataView>()
 )).Returns(queryResultSummaryMoq);
```